# Use of [self.labelIBOutlet release] vs [labelIBOutlet release]

Tags: ios, memory-management, dealloc

I have been playing a bit with the memory in order to be a good memory citizen on the iPhone SDK.

However I still struggle to understand the difference between **"self.something"** and just **"something"**.

As far as I understood, **"self.something"** means ask to the class for "something", but there is something wrong on my thought. Let's see the example:

I have worked with the memory releasing:

1. `[self.labelIBOUtlet release]` *-> It crash*
2. `[labelIBOUtlet release]`      *-> It doesn't.*

Can anyone please explain me what is the reason?

Thank you!

EDIT:

This is the information I have set on the header file:

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel * labelIBOutlet ;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel * labelIBOutlet ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand the meaning of "property"
the use of "dot" is just a faster way to call "special methods" created just to "set" and "get" variable-property.

as example, you could have your own class/UIView which uses a subView:

in myView.h

```
@interface myView : UIView  {
    UIWebView *webView;
}
```

if you do just this you have not a "property", but just an ojbect...
so in your myView.m you try to use the "dot" like this:

```
NSLog(@"%i", self.webView.frame.size.width);
```

then you get an error, you cannot do that, xCode says:
 error: accessing unknown 'webView' getter method

that just means that a the method "webView" doesn't exist...
'couse when you call "self.webView" you just call a method called "webView"...
this method just return the pointer to your value.
and when you call:

```
self.webView=someValue;
```

you are just calling the method "setWebView", a method that just set your object with someValue...

but so... where do those 2 invisible methods come from?

they are created by xCode itself if you tell it to use webView as a property...
in our example, add some lines:

in myView.h

```
    @interface myView : UIView  {
        UIWebView *webView;
    }

@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIWebView *webView;
```

in myView.m

```
@implementation myView

@synthesize webView;

// ...
```

doing this xCode will add the 2 methods "webView" and "setWebView" for you,
and now you can call:

```
NSLog(@"%i", self.webView.frame.size.width);
```

with no error...

and you can put value (of the right format, in this case a pointer to an existing UIWebView)
just calling:

```
self.webView = aUIWebView;
```

and remember to release it, 'couse you used "retain" in :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIWebView *webView;
```

release it with:

```
[webView release];
```

Comment: Thank you meronix, I can not see the relation of your answer with my question. I mean, that is a good description of the getter and setters using properties and synthesize. But still don't understand why using [self.labelIBOutlet release] makes the app crash. If I'm not mistaken, in that releasing situation I'm not using either getters or setters!

Comment: @LeoUKSP: well, yes, that's the point: you are doing it... "self.labelIBOutlet" is exactly a call to the getter method for labelIBOutlet

Comment: @LeoUKSP: just try this, it may help you to understand: add yourself the getter method, add this: -(id)labelIBOutlet{return labelIBOutlet;} ... and now try again to call [self.labelIBOutlet release]; ... without using @property and @synthetize, i mean... it shouldn't crash anymore...

Comment: Umm, there is something wrong in my understanding, I have tried it and still makes crash.

Comment: If you call it in `dealloc` is it happen before `[super dealloc]`?

Comment: @LeoUKSP: mhm, then it may depend on the allocation of your object and retain count when you call it... anyway, if the focus is on the "dot" calling, just try my example with an object, to make an easier way use a NSSTring object...

Comment: Ok ok, now it works. As far as I understand using "self" I'm calling getter or setter, that is the problem. Instead of releasing I'm calling those methods, that is the reason for the crash. Thank you meronix!!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have labelIBOUtlet in your object declared it will fall on calling self.labelIBOUtlet because it do not exist.
self == is in the object which is declared in header file

hope it makes it clear

Comment: Hi Csabi, thank you for your awnser. I don't know whether I understand well your response. According to that, it shouldn't crash! Edit: Sorry, I didn't say I'm setting properly the label on the header file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you @synthesize labelIBOutlet in the implementation file?